# React-Select component closeMenuOnSelect={false} still closing

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-select

I'm trying to do a basic isMulti react-select dropdown but even when set to false it's still closing it after every click.
I tried to set it to true to test and its the same...

```html
            <Select
              components={animatedComponents}
              isMulti
              options={colourOptions}
              // menuIsOpen={true}
              closeMenuOnSelect={false}
            />
```

Comment: which version are you using ?

Comment: "react-select": "^3.1.1",

Answer (score 3):

I don't really know why but after many research just add:

```js
blurInputOnSelect={false}
```

and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

`<Select menuIsOpen={true} components={animatedComponent} options={options} isMulti closeMenuOnSelect={false} />`

Try this way without putting any comment within the Select tag

Comment: It's working because of the "menuIsOpen". but I don't want it in default to be open. or to be always open.

Answer (score 0):

Yo have to put your custom menu inside <components.Menu> component. Something like this:

```
import Select, { components } from "react-select"; 

const CustomMenu = (props: MenuProps) => {
        return (
            <components.Menu className="react-select--availability" {...props}>
                <div>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="saka-test" />
                    <label htmlFor="saka-test">grdonifgeornh</label>
                </div>
            </components.Menu>
        );
    };
```